# Orbit Controls autorotate once

Tags: three.js, aframe

Orbit controls allow us to autorotate the camera around the object. It does not allow us to specify the number of loops. I want to autorotate the camera only once around the object, on loading. Any idea on how to do this?

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Trying to stop the rotation when the current world position is same as the initial world position of the camera. Stuck here. @2pha

Comment: If you share your code with your attempt it will be easier for people to suggest solutions. https://glitch.com/~aframe is a great option